# Relevance of $\mathrm{GL}(n, \mathbb{Q})$

Tags: linear-algebra, representation-theory, general-linear-group

When studying topics such as representation theory, Lie theory or even just linear algebra, we see the vector spaces $\mathrm{GL}(n, \mathbb{K})$ for $\mathbb{K} \in \{\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{C}\}$ all the time. General linear groups over finite fields also have their applications and the general linear group $\mathrm{GL}(2, \mathbb{Q}_p)$ is immensely important in local Langlands Correspondence.
Therefore, I asked myself whether there are any mathematical applications, e.g. in the aforementioned fields of study, for $\mathrm{GL}(n, \mathbb{Q})$ or in general for $\mathrm{GL}(n, \mathbb{K})$ where $\mathbb{K}$ is of characteristic $0$, but not algebraically closed.

Comment: Have you looked at Bourbaki? They would have many of the theorem in the most general context. My understanding is that there are a lot of stuff that can still be done over $\mathbb{Q}$, but working over an uncountable algebraically closed field of characteristic 0 has a lot of advantages in terms of proofs etc.

Comment: One enormous use is in automorphic forms/representation theory, where $GL(n,\mathbb Q)$ is a discrete subgroup of the adele group $GL(n,\mathbb A)$, the modern substitute for $SL(2,\mathbb Z)$ acting on the complex upper half-plane. But is this the sort of thing of interest to you? It's not really about the repn theory of the group $GL(n,\mathbb Q)$.

Comment: Studying $GL(n,\Bbb Q)$ can lead to some insight regarding field extensions (e.g. in the context of Galois theory)

Comment: Thanks for your answers - @ ArB No, but I will do so. @ paul garrett I will have to go deeper into the theory of automorphic forms/representations to understand the mathematics behind Adele groups in rigour - do you have any sources which helped you learn this theory? @ Ben Grossmann Could you also please refer to any sources where I could look at those results? Thank you all again!